# Husky/lint-staged pre-commit formatting issue

Tags: husky, git-husky, lint-staged

Running husky/lint-staged hook for pre-commit formatting (working fine).
Having one strange bug where for some reason on one file it keeps formatting the file with a spacing of 1 tab instead of 2 spaces.
(husky/lint-staged seems to rewrite/reformat the entire file with tab spacing but just this file)

No idea why it is doing this, anyone encountered a issue like this before?
Any help on this greatly appreciated as I am pulling my hair out at this stage.

Kind regards,
UI

```
"husky": {
   "hooks": {
        "pre-commit": "lint-staged"
    }
},
"lint-staged": {
    "src/**/*.{js,scss}": [
        "prettier --write",
        "git add"
    ]
},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found solution to above issue.
Updated Prettier to V2.0.5 and added .prettierrc file.
Resolved all issues with Husky commits.
(Removed git add command as automatic with lint-staged V10)

```
"husky": {
   "hooks": {
        "pre-commit": "lint-staged"
    }
},
"lint-staged": {
    "src/**/*.{js,scss}": [
        "prettier --write"
    ]
},
```